# CIFilter have by using the imageview is distorted (iOS)

Tags: ios, uiimageview, cifilter

I am developing a camera application is distorted image . horizontal pressure button effect in photographs. Vertical Take a photo of the current no problems .Bug horizontal photo.

[no effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYDVB.jpg)

[turn effect button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys25e.jpg)

```
CIImage *rawImageData;
rawImageData =[[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:image];
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIPhotoEffectInstant"];

[filter setDefaults];
[filter setValue:rawImageData forKey:@"inputImage"];

CIImage *filteredImageData = [filter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:filteredImageData];


self.imagegr.image = image;
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `UIImage` from a `CIImage` with the technique you're using creates images that don't respect `contentMode`. Try this (written in Swift, I'm afraid, but not difficult to rewrite in Objective C):

```
let ciContext = CIContext()

let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(
  filteredImageData,
  fromRect: filteredImageData.extent)

self.imagegr.image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
```

The `CIContext` can be created once and reused.

Comment: Some codes are said to objective c but did not solve the problem.